# How do I call a InventoryClickEvent in a boolean?

Tags: java, bukkit

I first created the inventory that will be opened:

```java
private void openGUI(Player player) {
    Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "DuelRequest" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]");

    ItemStack accept = new ItemStack(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK);
    ItemMeta acceptMeta = accept.getItemMeta();

    ItemStack decline = new ItemStack(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
    ItemMeta declineMeta = decline.getItemMeta();

    acceptMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Accept!");
    accept.setItemMeta(acceptMeta);

    declineMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Decline!");
    decline.setItemMeta(declineMeta);

    inv.setItem(3, accept);
    inv.setItem(5, decline);

    player.openInventory(inv);
}
```

Then I created the command that will be run:

```java
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("duel")) {
        if (!(args.length == 1)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Usage: /duel <Player>");
            return true;
        } else if (args.length == 1) {

            Player p = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
            if (p != null) {
                if (p.equals(sender)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You cannot duel yourself!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You sent a duel request to " + ChatColor.BLUE + p.getName());
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You recieved a duel request from " + ChatColor.BLUE + sender.getName());
                    openGUI(p);
                }
            }
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Player not found!");
        }
    }
    return true;
```

I Then created an event that is called when a players clicks their inventory.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
private void onClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {

    if (!ChatColor.stripColor(e.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("[DuelRequest]"))
        return;

    Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
    e.setCancelled(true);

    switch (e.getCurrentItem().getType()) {
    case EMERALD_BLOCK:
        player.closeInventory();
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You accepted the request");
        player.getInventory().setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD));
        player.getInventory().setItem(1, new ItemStack(Material.BOW));
        player.getInventory().setItem(2, new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 2));
        player.getInventory().setItem(3, new ItemStack(Material.ARROW, 32));
        player.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_HELMET));
        player.getInventory().setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE));
        player.getInventory().setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS));
        player.getInventory().setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS));
        break;
    case REDSTONE_BLOCK:
        player.closeInventory();
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You denied the request!");
        break;
    default:
        player.closeInventory();
        break;
    }
}
```

So, what i want to happen is..

When a player types /duel , the  (target) will have an inventory opened in front of them with an option to accept or decline the duel request. I have tested this and it works as expected. If they decline they will receive a message telling them they rejected it, if they accept they will be given a Kit to duel with. This also works as expected. However, i need to be able to give the sender of the /duel command the same kit, but i don't know how to. So... When the  (target) accepts the duel, both players will receive a kit so they can both fight.

Is there a way of calling for the `onClick` event inside the `onCommand`?
Or is there a way to contact the sender of the command from inside the `onClick` event?

I am average with Bukkit coding but obviously still have a lot to learn so any help/constructive criticism is always helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), to store the player that sent the duel request to a player:

```java
Map<UUID, UUID> duels = new HashMap<UUID, UUID>();
```

[`HashMaps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) are used to store a value for another value, it's effectively a large collection of variables.

When the sender runs the command, you could use:

```java
duels.put(target.getUniqueId(), sender.getUniqueId());
```

So, when the target accepts the duel, you could get the sender of the request with:

```java
duels.get(target.getUniqueId());
```

Here's what your `onCommand()` could look like:

```java
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("duel")) {
    if (!(args.length == 1)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Usage: /duel <Player>");
        return true;
    } else if (args.length == 1) {

        Player p = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        if (p != null) {
            if (p.equals(sender)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You cannot duel yourself!");
                return true;
            } else {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You sent a duel request to " + ChatColor.BLUE + p.getName());
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You recieved a duel request from " + ChatColor.BLUE + sender.getName());
                openGUI(p);

                //Put the player in the HashMap here
                duels.put(p.getUniqueId(), ((Player) sender).getUniqueId());
            }
        }
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " Player not found!");
    }
}
return true;
```

And your `onClick()` could look like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
//It's better if you make your events public
//and not private
public void onClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {

if (!ChatColor.stripColor(e.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("[DuelRequest]"))
    return;

Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
e.setCancelled(true);

//get the UUID stored in the duels HashMap for the player's UUID as a key
UUID uuid = duels.get(player.getUniqueId());

//Get the challenger from the UUID above
Player challenger = Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);

switch (e.getCurrentItem().getType()) {
case EMERALD_BLOCK:
    player.closeInventory();
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You accepted the request");
    player.getInventory().setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD));
    player.getInventory().setItem(1, new ItemStack(Material.BOW));
    player.getInventory().setItem(2, new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE, 2));
    player.getInventory().setItem(3, new ItemStack(Material.ARROW, 32));
    player.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_HELMET));
    player.getInventory().setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE));
    player.getInventory().setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS));
    player.getInventory().setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS));

    //give the kit to the challenger here
    //Maybe make a method, giveKit(Player p), to clean up your code
    //Then you could run giveKit(challenger) and giveKit(player)
    break;
case REDSTONE_BLOCK:
    player.closeInventory();
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " You denied the request!");


    //tell the challenger that player denied their duel request
    challenger.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "HuntsCraft" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "]" + ChatColor.RED + player.getName + " denied your duel request");
    break;
default:
    player.closeInventory();
    break;
}
}
```

If you wanted to check if a `UUID` exists in the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you could use `duels.containsKey(uuid)`

Make sure to never store `Player` objects inside of [`HashMaps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), because it can cause memory leaks if the player leaves the server, for instance. The best way to store player information is by storing their `UUID`, or by storing their username.

Comment: @MattyFenny No problem! HashMaps are very confusing in the beginning. It took me a long time to figure out why I should use them. Also, I just updated my answer to include that you shouldn't store `Player` objects in HashMaps, because it can cause memory leaks.

Anyways, if you think this solves your problem, make sure to accept the answer so others can find it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much! quick question.. Do hashmaps work in a similar way to array lists? so could i do something like this in my onCommand....

'if(!(duels.contains(p)) || (!(duels.contains(sender){
//Do whats meant to happen
}else{
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Either you or " + p.getName() + " Are in a duel already!";

Comment: @MattyFenny Yes, I just updated my answer to include that. Instead of using `duels.contains(player)`, though, the method is `duels.containsKey(player)`